# Is the return value of pycurl.CurlMulti.info_read still usable after call to remove_handle?

Tags: libcurl, pycurl

I am using `pycurl.CurlMulti` interface in `python3` and I want to use `info_read` to check for the succeeded and failed connections.

According to the documentation of the `c` interface [curl_multi_info_read](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_info_read.html) of `libcurl`:

> WARNING: The data the returned pointer points to will not survive calling curl_multi_cleanup, curl_multi_remove_handle or curl_easy_cleanup.

However, the documentation of [pycurl.CurlMulti](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/curlmultiobject.html) does not mention whether the `curl error message` in the return value of `pycurl.CurlMulti.info_read()` is valid after a call to `curl_multi_remove_handle`.

The only way to check this is read the source code of `pycurl`.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code for [pycurl.CurlMulti.info_read](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/blob/master/src/multi.c#L798) and it shows that:

```c
        /* When an error occurs */
        else {
            /* Create a result tuple that will get added to err_list. */
            PyObject *v = Py_BuildValue("(Ois)", (PyObject *)co, (int)msg->data.result, co->error);
            /* Append curl object to list of objects which failed */
            if (v == NULL || PyList_Append(err_list, v) != 0) {
                Py_XDECREF(v);
                goto error;
            }
            Py_DECREF(v);
        }
```

where `co` is retrieved from [L781](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/blob/master/src/multi.c#L781):

```c
        /* Fetch the curl object that corresponds to the curl handle in the message */
        res = curl_easy_getinfo(msg->easy_handle, CURLINFO_PRIVATE, (char **) &co);
```

And `CURLINFO_PRIVATE` and `co->error` is set at [src/easy.c#L52](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/blob/master/src/easy.c#L52):

```c
    /* Set curl error buffer and zero it */
    res = curl_easy_setopt(self->handle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, self->error);
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        return (-1);
    }
    memset(self->error, 0, sizeof(self->error));

    /* Set backreference */
    res = curl_easy_setopt(self->handle, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, (char *) self);
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        return (-1);
    }
```

which means that given the `pycurl.Curl` object is not reused for another connection or destroyed, it should be pretty safe to use the `curl error message` in the return value of `pycurl.CurlMulti.info_read()`.

This answer gives me another interesting fact:

It is not safe to set `CURLOPT_PRIVATE` on the `pycurl.Curl` object.